# Calculate difference between two dates

Tags: r

My dates  in the txt file are like, start date= "011589" and end date is "122390". How can I calculate the duration using R.

I tried 
mydata$startdate=as.Date(mydata$startdate)
but it did not work

Comment: You need the `format` i.e. `as.Date("011589", "%m%d%y")`

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using `format`

```
Start <- as.Date("011589", "%m%d%y")
Start
#[1] "1989-01-15"
End <- as.Date("122390", "%m%d%y")
End
#[1] "1990-12-23"
```

If we need the difference in 'days'

```
as.vector(difftime(End, Start, units='days'))
#[1] 707
```

Or just use `-` to get the difference in 'days'.  The above method is more flexible as we can specify the `units`

```
as.vector(End-Start)
#[1] 707
```